# apache-cxf dosgi restful service as eclipse plug-in weirdness

Tags: eclipse, rest, eclipse-plugin, cxf

I'm in the process of exposing some of the data generated in one OSGi bundle with a REST interface so it can be consumed with typical http requests afterwards by anyone. To do this I'm using a combination of apache-cxf, JAX-RS and Jetty (for testing purposes mostly).

My whole application is distributed in two ways:

- Core: Runs a set of minimal bundles as an OSGi framework.
- Full: Core + plus a set of plugins to be used within Eclipse, in a graphical way, to put it that way.

While in the Core launch configuration I can make this work without any problems, have a look at the MANIFEST:

```
Require-Bundle: cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution;bundle-version="1.3.1",org.eclipse.core.runtime, org.eclipse.osgi.services;bundle-version="3.3.0", org.mortbay.jetty.server;bundle-version="6.1.23", org.mortbay.jetty.util;bundle-version="6.1.23"
```

When I try to launch the Full distribution, jetty server does not seem to start and thus, the RESTful service is not working properly. Full distribution comes with a lot more plugins, mostly related with wizards, perspectives and so on. Root of this problem is somehow related with the cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution bundle, and can be tackled by "forcing" auto-start of this bundle to true, instead of default (check image below):

[image]

While this is OK, my question is ...why is this happening? And second and most important, I distribute the Full distribution via an update site, so users can download it, open perspective and start using it, that said, will this affect the final distribution? Is there a way I can control this auto-start=true for the apache-cxf bundle in the update site?

Hope I can make myself clear...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't like answering my own questions, but since I'm getting no feedback and maybe someone else has the same problem...here it goes

I decided to change the whole design of my restful bundle, by not using apache-cxf, since it is really not needed. All I need to do what I want is the embedded Jetty server and javax for dealing with HttpRequests and HttpResponses. Thus, I get rid of dependecies with third party libraries, leveraging the launching problems at the same time.

Got the ideas from these official sites in Eclipe:

[Embedding an HTTP server in Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_equinox.php)

[Writing a bundle-based server application](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_writing_application.php)

Besides, a more hands-on tutorials can be also found here:

[OSGi as a Web Server application](http://bryanhunt.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/osgi-as-a-web-application-server/)

[Extending Eclipse: displaying HTML content from a bundled archive](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/11/11/extending-eclipse-displaying-html-content-from-a-bundled-archive.html)

Special thanks to both authors for the enlightenment :).